# How to Rename minecraft pe server ip

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, hosting

I was wondering that how some people name there minecraft pe server,  like net.craft.com . I have a server too but its ip keeps on changing ( sometime 192.168.43:19132 or 10.47.60.221:19132) when i connect and disconnect to internet so is there any way I can rename my server ip to com.familycraft.net.Everytime I have to tell my cousins the server ip to play. My server run on poketmine. And is an online server. Runs on Photon max Internet (USB modem).
THANK YOU

Answer (score 3):

The only way to have a Name as address is to have a Domain with that name.

With the [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) this name will determine the Server IP.

You can try a Dynamic DNS Service which offers that Server Administrators which IP is Dynamic (IP Changes after X Hours) to have a Domain.

So unfortunately it's quite easier to tell him everytime the IP of the server than trie to configure a Dynamic DNS Service or have a own Dedicated Server with real Domain in some kind of Datacenter. And additional you can only have the name the Dynamic DNS Service gives you, or the Domain you bought, so you can't choose whatever name you whish.

Im not even sure if your USB Modem could use a Dynamic DNS Provider.

Comment: Sorry but can you explain me in normal English. I didn't understand the term dns. What is it. I am a beginner in this server related things

Comment: Thats why i added a Link to the Wikipedia Page of DNS. In Short, DNS is some kind of system which converts a Domain Name (like google.com) into a IP Address.

Answer (score 0):

There are services designed to give you a human-friendly name that points to your IP address; I use one called [No-IP](http://www.noip.com/). They have a client that sits on your computer so that when your IP address changes, it updates the DNS record for you. That way, you can always go to the same domain name to get to your computer.